# How to pause the video when popup is closed in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using Bootstrap 5 Modal Popup, I embedded an Iframe in the popup box and everything is working fine but the thing is that When I am closing the Popup the video is not stoping/pausing and even the Popup is closed it is still Running in the background and I tried to stop it via Jquery but don't know why it is not working.
So can anyone please tell me how to pause/stop the video when the popup is closed?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = $("#how-it-works-video").attr('src');

  $("#exampleModal").on('hide', function() {
    $("#how-it-works-video").attr('src', '');
  });

  $("#exampleModal").on('show', function() {
    $("#how-it-works-video").attr('src', url);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  How it works
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="modal-body">      
      <iframe id="how-it-works-video" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BrD3abCyuzw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Edit: I noticed the video is not playing in Stackoverflow Code editor but if you use any other code editor it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap v5 have different event listeners.
You have to change **show** to **shown.bs.modal** / **hide** to **hide.bs.modal**.

```
  $("#exampleModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#how-it-works-video").attr('src', '');
        console.log('Unloaded')
  });

  $("#exampleModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#how-it-works-video").attr('src', url);
        console.log('Loaded')
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39gmbk6p/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer I highly Appreciate it

Comment: if you feel the question will become helpful for other people You can upvote it

Comment: This seems not to work in production for me I don't know if it's a caching issue or something, but here is the website: https://wayneswildworld.com/about-us.html                If you go to the bottom of that page you will see the video.

Comment: @Wayne you have undefined variable **url**. You need to replace **url** with youtube url or define it as in the jsfiddle example